# ffmpeg transparent waveform and solid background

Tags: ffmpeg, transparent, waveform

Im trying to create waveform image with transparent wave and solid background color. Im find the similar topic here:

[FFMPEG waveform transparent, background solid color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149739/ffmpeg-waveform-transparent-background-solid-color)

but the answer not working for me :( 
Maybe do you know why this code suspend the program in console command.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex \    "[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,compand=gain=-6, \
    showwavespic=s=600x120:colors=white,negate[a]; \
    color=red:600x120[c]; \
    [c][a]alphamerge"  -vframes 1 output.png
```

Comment: Share full console output.

Comment: Here: https://prnt.sc/j1le2x and program is stopped on line "encoder : Lavc57.107.100 png" I was trying change color from white on blue but the same effect. However the code from author with the original topic is working but there is a black color

Comment: The waveform color has to be white since it will be used an an alpha channel. Anyway, try with another mp3 and on another machine.

Comment: The command not working on linux (debian) and windows 10 machine with installed ffmpeg tool :( I must generate waveform like this on linux systems.

Comment: Here is how I did it on Win7. Maybe you can modify the code to work with Linux. [link]https://pastebin.com/raw/CD3umQHh

Answer (score 0):

OK, so finally i do it in 3 steps

first generate black waveform on color solid background:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mp3 -f lavfi -i color=s=600x240:c=red -filter_complex "[0:a]showwavespic=s=600x240:colors=#000000[fg];[1:v][fg]overlay=format=rgb" -frames:v 1 output.png
```

We can use other background color(in hex) like c:0xC7C7C7
 and next cute black wafevorm

```
ffmpeg -y -i output.png -vf colorkey=0x000000:0.6:0.2 Finished.png
```

and delete temp file

```
rm output.png
```

Thanks guys for help.